# Job graph is too large error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been attempting to run an apache beam job on Dataflow, but I'm getting an error from GCP with the following message:

```
The job graph is too large. Please try again with a smaller job graph, or split your job into two or more smaller jobs.
```

I have run jobs with larger graphs in the past and had no problems. The job also runs fine locally with DirectRunner. There are about 12 nodes in the graph including a read from Bigquery step, a `WriteToText` step and a `CoGroupByKey` step.

Is there a way to increase the graph size Dataflow is willing to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small pipeline, the most likely cause of this is accidentally serializing extra data into your DoFns (or other serialized code).  Do you have any large objects in your main class that are being automatically included in closures?  If so, the easiest thing to do is do build up your pipeline in a static function.

It's not possible to raise the graph size limit.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I thought it would be fine to send a payload of ~35MB to each worker as serialized objects and misinterpreted the error message as the computation had too many steps. The problem is fixed now, thank you.

Comment: also if you put autoscaling and max number of worker to something like 1000 it will increase 1000 times

Comment: Hitting this now after upgrading to Beam 2.10 and Scio 0.7.2. I have a feeling that I am overserializing, but I'm not sure how to track it down. Any suggestions?